# npm install stack error win32-x64-57_binding.node not found

Tags: npm-install, node-sass

When I run with npm install,I got this error.[This is the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/st8u4.png)
I already reinstalled node and delete all npm or npm cache in C Disk,but the error still happen

Answer (score 1):

Node 9 (module 57) isn't supported for node-sass 4.5.0. You need to upgrade to 4.7.2 or downgrade your Node version

Comment: Thank you very much,I already downgrade to node 6, now it works fine.